# How to access the parent's component method from its nested component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I have one component `CreateOCSServiceForm` which is calling other component `ListPage` from its render method. This `ListPage` is expecting a component named `NodeList` from its attribute  named `ListComponent` and again the `NodeList` is expecting a component `NodeTableRow` from its attribute named `Row` like this -

```
 //Getting called from NodeList's attribute
const NodeTableRow: React.FC<NodeTableRowProps> = ({ obj: node, index, key, style, customData }) => {
return (
<TableRow index={index} trKey={key} style={style}>
  <td data-key="0" className="pf-c-table__check" role="gridcell">
    <input type="checkbox" checked={false}
      onChange={(e) => { onSelect(e, e.target.checked, index, node) }}
    />
  </td>
  <TableData>
    ---
  </TableData>
  <TableData>
   ---
  </TableData>
  <TableData>
     ----
  </TableData>
  <TableData>
    ----
  </TableData>
</TableRow>
 );
};

//Getting called from ListPage's attribute
const NodesList = props => <Table customData={props.data} {...props} Row={NodeTableRow} onSelect={onSelect} />;


//main component which is calling ListPage 
export const CreateOCSServiceForm: React.FC<CreateOCSServiceFormProps> = (props1) => {
 const title = 'Create New OCS Service';
 const [error, setError] = React.useState('');
 const [inProgress, setProgress] = React.useState(false);

 const [rowData, setRowData] = React.useState(null);

 const onSelect = (event, isSelected, virtualRowIndex, rowData1) => {
    console.log(rowData1, 'customData');
    console.log('isSelected', isSelected, 'virtualRowIndex', virtualRowIndex, 'rowData', rowData1);
    rowData[virtualRowIndex].selected = true;
    setRowData(rowData);
 };
return (
   <ListPage kind={NodeModel.kind} showTitle={false} ListComponent={NodeList} />}
   )
}
```

The problem is that the NodeList and NodeTableRow components have to accees `onSelect` method which is defined on the `CreateOCSServiceForm` component, but how should I expose this `onSelect` method to them. Don't want to make `onSelect` method global as I have to use  CreateOCSServiceForm`  states inside it. I can't modify NodeList and ListPage component, its existing components in my code base and modifying it will result in breaking other pages. We need to pass the functionality of the OnSelect property in NodeList component.

Any guidance will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pass a callback as a property... and I never have seen someone passing a Component as props, you may try use component children...

Comment: @DennisVash I can't modify  NodeList and ListPage component as its existing component and changing it can result in breaking other pages.

Comment: @DennisVash nothing wrong with passing a Component as a prop, it's equivalent to [Strategy Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), even if [Render Props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) (children as a function) is more common in React, the use cases for the 2 patterns can be different

Answer (score 0):

Given the constrains:

1. > NodeList and NodeTableRow components have to accees onSelect method
2. > I can't modify NodeList and ListPage component

I would assume that `ListPage` already supports either the `onSelect` prop:

```
return (
  <ListPage onSelect={onSelect} kind={NodeModel.kind} showTitle={false} ListComponent={NodeList} />
)
```

or some other way to pass the method (but you need to look in the documentation), e.g.:

```
return (
  <ListPage options={{ListComponentOnSelect: onSelect}} ... />
)
```